# How to save the response in the Postman same as the name I mentioned it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postman

This piece of code will put all the data(string) as an XML format in the Postman. But when I try to save the response in the Postman so, it will save as **response.xml**, which I don't want. I want that Postman will save my XML content in the form of **filename.xml**.

So, how should I proceed with? I have to google it and found that something like attachment, content-type, and all must be used. But, didn't solve my case. Please help with your suggestion.

For simplicity, I have reduced the code. Here, **graphics** is **string** datatype.

```
public ActionResult GetXML()
{
    string filename = "Demo";
    return Content(graphics, "application/xml");
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you want that the `GetXML` action to acts like a file download? If not I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want the GetXML to treat as the File Download. But the filename should not be like response.xml (by default in Postman). I want filename.xml

Comment: @Ackdari did you get it? What I meant to say. I want it simple that the Postman will save/download the file with the name filename.xml, not response.xml.

Comment: I think you can not control what postman can do or not do from your server code.. The response from the API is loaded in the postman and it is not local content to postman and  so when user wants to save that response it is postman's internal settings to decide the default filename while saving but user can always change the file name in the Save As Dialog... BTW why you want to control the filename used by the postman?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you. So how could you tell me how should return this XML data as an XML file which should be automatically downloaded in the web browser. Could you please write the code for it. 
Simply convert this XML data in the form of a file and auto-download in the web browser when client get the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Content-Disposition` header so the that browser prompts for saving response.

You can do that by using following approach.

```
public IActionResult Getxml()
{
        var xmlData =
            "<records><record><Name>Camacho, Sydnee Q.</Name><Id>1</Id><Age>19</Age><City>Podolsk</City></record><record><Name>Bowman, Lester V.</Name><Id>2</Id><Age>21</Age><City>Padang</City></record></records>";

        //sampleFile.xml can be replaced by any filename of your choice.
        var fileName = "sampleFile.xml";
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
        return Content(xmlData, "application/xml", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

With this change when this URL is browsed in the browser it will prompt save dialog with `sampleFile.xml` populated as filename.

[image: Save File Dialog From Browser]

Also when you save the response from postman it will show `sampleFile.xml` populated as file name in the dialog.

[image: Save File Dialog From Postman]

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!......
I loved it. That's what I exactly want.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [`FileContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for a file download.

```cs
public ActionResult GetXML()
{
    var fileName = "Demo.xml";
    var xml = "...";

    return new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml), "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
    {
        FileDownloadName = fileName,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the response headers so that the download client automatically treats the content as a "file", the key is the `ContentDisposition` header, this is how we pass the filename back.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetXMLFile()
{
    string filename = "Demo";
    var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(graphics);
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(byteArray), byteArray.Length)
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") //attachment will force download
    {
        FileName = filename
    };

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code.
But I have pasted this code and earlier I did the same, but somehow, it not downloading.